# change div with info when click to owl-prev/owl-next

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a carousel, and a box on the bottom that shows information about the picture that is in the carousel. I need to make this in the way that when you click on the arrows of the carousel (owl-prev and owl-next), it has to change the picture and at the same time it has to change the information box.

```
 <div class="textCarousel col-md-24 col-sm-24 col-xs-24">
       <div class="projectInfo visibleFrame">
            <a href=""><img id="arrowBrowseDown" src="propertiesImages/arrowBrowseDown.jpg" alt="arrow"/></a>  
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-24">
              <h1>client</h1>
              <p>Quadrant Construction</p>
          </div> 
             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-24">
              <h1>project</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
          </div> 
             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-24">
              <h1>Utilitas</h1>
              <p class="utilitasItem">Saved Cost<span class="utilitasSpec">£10k Electric</span></p>
              <p class="utilitasItem">Timescales<span class="utilitasSpec">Achieved</span></p>
               <p class="utilitasItem">Budget<span class="utilitasSpec">331</span></p>
          </div> 
             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-24">
              <h1>testimonial</h1>
              <p class="testimonialText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
          </div> 
            </div>
           <div class="projectInfo">
            <a href=""><img id="arrowBrowseDown" src="propertiesImages/arrowBrowseDown.jpg" alt="arrow"/></a>  
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-24">
              <h1>client 2</h1>
              <p>Quadrant Construction</p>
          </div> 
             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-24">
              <h1>project 2</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
          </div> 
             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-24">
              <h1>Utilitas 2</h1>
              <p class="utilitasItem">Saved Cost<span class="utilitasSpec">£10k Electric</span></p>
              <p class="utilitasItem">Timescales<span class="utilitasSpec">Achieved</span></p>
               <p class="utilitasItem">Budget<span class="utilitasSpec">331</span></p>
          </div> 
             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-24">
              <h1>testimonial 2</h1>
              <p class="testimonialText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
          </div> 
            </div>
           <div class="projectInfo visibleFrame">
            <a href=""><img id="arrowBrowseDown" src="propertiesImages/arrowBrowseDown.jpg" alt="arrow"/></a>  
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-24">
              <h1>client 3</h1>
              <p>Quadrant Construction</p>
          </div> 
             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-24">
              <h1>project 3</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
          </div> 
             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-24">
              <h1>Utilitas 3</h1>
              <p class="utilitasItem">Saved Cost<span class="utilitasSpec">£10k Electric</span></p>
              <p class="utilitasItem">Timescales<span class="utilitasSpec">Achieved</span></p>
               <p class="utilitasItem">Budget<span class="utilitasSpec">331</span></p>
          </div> 
             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-24">
              <h1>testimonial 3</h1>
              <p class="testimonialText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
          </div> 
            </div>
             </div> 


and my js that does not have any sense, I know:

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".owl-next").click(function(){
  var item = $(this).attr('class');   
    var infoBox = $(".textCarousel .visibleFrame").html;

    $('.textCarousel . visibleFrame').children('div').attr('src',infoBox);
    $("#currentImgCarousel").trigger('owl.next');
  });


 });
```

the thing is, `.textCarousel` is the class of the div that contents the box with the information, each info (for each picture has de class `.projectInfo`), I put a class `.visibleFrame` to the first `.projectInfo` (so the first picture), my theory was, every time I click .owl-next it will move the class `.visibleFrame` to the next one, and the opposite, if I click `.owl-prev` it will move `.visibleFrame` class to the `.projectInfo` div that it founds before this one.

I don't know how to start!!!!! as I need to know how many items I have in the loop and not idea how to move the class to another :( with removeClass and addClass I supose but don't know how to start... any help???

Comment: please provide a fiddle mate.It might be lot easier

Comment: don't forget the css in the fiddle to.